# ¿Cómo automatizar la propiedad de la clase Number?

Tags: javascript

Si tengo:

```js
Number.prototype.abs = function(n){
    return n * 2;
};

var b = (1).abs(2);
console.log(b);
```

Que solo se colocase directamente el número y la función como lo hace un `toUpperCase()` , que no necesita pasar parámetros, porque solo dentro del método puedo poner `"this"` que se referirá a esa cadena, pero en el caso de la clase `number` no me puedo referir a this, o sea, si coloco `(5).abs();` no

```
var b = 2.abs();
```

Por ende, según yo haría:

```
Number.prototype.abs = function(n) {
    return this * 2;
};
```

Cosa que no me resulta, ¿es imposible?

En relacion al snippet que funciona:

Y además, ¿por que al colocar `1.abs(2);` no funciona y al colocar `(1).abs(2);` sí funciona?

Comment: Eduardo, tu consulta no se entiende, por favor trata de redactarla mejor

Comment: es como lo interpreta el compilador obviamente realizando 1.abs() lo lee como una cadena completa en cambio al realizar el (1) entiende que el valor es un tipo numero intenta hacer minuevacadena.length va a dar error en cambio "minuevacadena".length funciona

Comment: ¿Qué crees que pasaría con los decimales si se pudiera hacer algo así?

Comment: Ya lo he editado Carlos

Comment: Ya entiendo ese aspecto Cesar, gracias por aclararmelo , pero lo demás aun no

Comment: A que te refieres con "automatizar la propiedad de la clase Number" ?

Comment: Osea, que no sea necesario pasarle por parametro el numero y que simplemente este lo tomara directamente como se hace en la clase string por ejemplo (5.49).abs(); eso seria pero en cambio debo hacer (5.49).abs(5.49)

Comment: @César pero ejecutando en una consola `1.54.toString()` lo convierte a cadena sin problema. _Probado desde Google Chrome_

Comment: Que raro Davlio , ya se me ha complicado..

Comment: debe existir algo más a fondo que nadie me ha dicho

Comment: @Davlio, claro porque es el segundo punto. JavaScript entiende lo que estás tratando de hacer. Pero no con un numero entero. En todo caso sería: `1.0.abs(2)` según el ejemplo.

Comment: Osea simplemente al colocarle un decimal ya sabe que es numero

Comment: @EduardoSebastian al colocarle un decimal ya se sobre entiende que el siguiente punto se aplica para llamar a un método ya que, obviamente, no existen números con más de un punto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tal vez me explique mejor con una respuesta. Comenzando con el tema de la función del prototipo. Es posible que te refieras al valor de un número llamando al método `valueOf()` como te han explicado en una de tus preguntas anteriores.

Considera el caso de elevar un número al cuadrado:

```js
Number.prototype.cuadrado = function() {
    return this.valueOf() ** 2;
};

console.log((3).cuadrado());
console.log((9).cuadrado());
```

---

Con respecto al tema del punto, como he mencionado en mis comentarios, para JavaScript no hay forma de saber que quieres usar un método con un número entero, es decir, si tienes `1.`, ¿cómo diferenciar entre querer llamar a un método o querer construir un número decimal? Es por eso que se usa el paréntesis en el caso de los enteros:

```
(3).cuadrado()
(9).cuadrado()
```

No ocurre lo mismo con los números decimales por la sencilla razón que al poner un segundo punto después de un decimal se entiende que se quiere hacer la llamada a un método. En ese caso no necesitas usar paréntesis:

```
3.1.cuadrado()
9.4.cuadrado()
```

Answer (score 1):

Veamos como funciona poco a poco.

En javascript tenemos objetos y primitivos (number, string, etc) sin embargo, cuando invocamos una funcion sobre un primitivo, por ejemplo `5.toString()`, javascript envuelve temporalmente el 5 en un objeto Number para usar la funcion **toString** y luego desecha el objeto conservando el primitivo.

Cuando creas un prototipo, en `this` tienes la referencia de tu objeto

```js
Number.prototype.abs = function(){
  return this; //This es la funcion
};
var b = 5; //No es necesario crear un new Number(5);
//Imprime la funcion en consola
console.log( b.abs() );
```

Sabiendo ésto y teniendo en cuenta que la función **valueOf** nos regresa el valor primitivo del objeto podemos regresar su valor primitivo.

```js
Number.prototype.abs = function(){
      return this.valueOf();
    };
var b = 5;
console.log( b.abs() );
```

Y ya puedes hacer las operaciones que desses por ejemplo multiplicar el valor primitivo por 10

```js
Number.prototype.abs = function(){
      return this.valueOf() * 10;
    };
var b = 5;
console.log( b.abs() );
```

Y tambien puedes pedir algun argumento, por ejemplo una funcion que multiplique por cualquier numero pasado en el argumento

```js
Number.prototype.abs = function(n){
      return this.valueOf() * n;
    };
var b = 5;
console.log( b.abs(100) ); 
console.log( b.abs(20) );
```